# Commenting a commented markup (Nested comments)

Tags: html

How can I easily comment and uncomment a big chunk of HTML markup that that includes some comment?

```
<body>
a lot of markups
 <!-- comment -->
a lot of markups
 <!-- comment -->
a lot of markups
</body>
```

Following do not work as desired (closing --> stops the comment section):

```
<body>
  <!-- 
    a lot of markups
     <!-- comment -->
    a lot of markups
     <!-- comment -->
    a lot of markups
   -->
</body>
```

Is there any alternative method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no `</style>` and `*/` tag in comment area use:

```
<style>
/*
comment
*/
</style>
```

If you have no `</script>` and `*/` tag in comment area use:

```
<script>
/*
comment
*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the closing `-->` will stop the comment section.

You can't natively nest comments in html - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4

What I do (though it doesn't completely 'automate' blocking) is to add a `/` into the close on any contained comments, it just makes it easier to do a find & replace if I want to pull them out of a section:

```
<div>
  <!-- 
    blah
    <!-- Blah --/>
    more blahs
  -->
</div>
```

Comment: The cited document says: “Authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.” It’s informal text, and the suggested method is really an error in SGML and HTML terms (this is complicated, as it depends on SGML concept of comment declaration) and will trigger error messages in validation.

Comment: using two dash inside a comment is invalid, <!-- -- --> is an invalid comments

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in HTML. Just like you cant nest multiline comments in C, C++ or Java.

Comment: It c-like languages `\\\` syntax can be used by an IDE to nest multiple comments

Comment: Yes, but you can't *nest multi-line comments* means you cant have multi-line comments inside multi-line comments.