# How can I comment a large chunk of HTML markup that contains a lot of "--" or ">"?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting a commented markup (Nested comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998915/commenting-a-commented-markup-nested-comments)

How can I comment a large chunk of HTML markup that contains a lot of `--` or `>` (or `-->`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it doesn't contain any `*/`you can surround it in

```
<script>
/*
Your html
*/
</script>
```

Comment: nice way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes unless it contains `-->`

If it does and you are using PHP here is a trick:

Start the comment `<?php /*` then end the comment with `*/?>`.